# How to alphabetically sort a text file in python without sort function?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have to alphabetically sort a text file where each new word is on a new line. I currently have the whitespace stripped and  my program prints the first letter attaching it to a integer with the ord function. I cannot use sort and I know I have to put it into a list just not sure how. This is what i wrote for the lists.

`lists = [ [] for _ in range( 26 ) ]`

Comment: Why can you not use `sort`?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the `sort()` method, the `sorted()` function is your next bet.

```
words = [...]
sorted_words = sorted(words)
```

Unlike `words.sort()`, using `sorted()` won't modify its input, and it works on arbitrary iterables.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following function to sort your list of words:

```
def qsort(array):
    if len(array) < 2:
        return array
    head, *tail = array
    less = qsort([item for item in tail if item < head])
    more = qsort([item for item in tail if item >= head])
    return less + [head] + more
```

Answer (score -2):

For the range command you have to put two exclusive integers as parameters for example range(0,11) will pick a number between 1 and 10. This is probably why you can use range(). Also you need to use a column to follow range():.

Comment: [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) actually works fine with just one parameter `n` (positive integer), and it will return a list (or a lazily evaluated iterator in Python 3.x) of all integers from ***0*** to `n-1`.  No colon necessary after `range` in this instance because it's a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).